# How to use 'or' command in python properly

Tags: python

This code does not, for some reason work. It works with the 'and' command but I'm not completely sure how to use 'or'. My  current code:

```
if (response1 not in symbols or letters):
    print("You did something wrong")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if it would've been better to use `&&` and `||` instead of `and` and `or`, just to make people realize the operators don't do the zillion things the English conjunctions do.

Answer (score 4):

The `or` in Python (and most programming languages for that matter) is not like the 'or' from spoken languages.
When you say

```
if (response1 not in symbols or letters)
```

Python actually interprets it as

```
if ((response1 not in symbols) or (letters))
```

which is not what you want. So what you should actually be doing is:

```
if ((response1 not in symbols) and (response1 not in letters))
```

Comment: @user3468137: In addition to this answer you can also read about [Expressions summary documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expressions). Especially [Boolean Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), [Expressions evaluation order](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) and [Operator Precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 1):

`or` is a logical operator. If the part before `or` is true-ish, then that is returned, and if not, the second part is.

So here, either `response1 not in symbols` is True and then that is returned, or otherwise `letters` is returned. If there are things in `letters` then it is true-ish itself, and the `if` statement will consider it True.

You're looking for

```
if (response1 not in symbols) and (response1 not in letters):
    print("You did something wrong")
```